# Conclusion in the proof that every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis regarding countable index set

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am working through a proof that every hilbert space has a orthogonal basis which lies dense in that Hilbert space. In the proof the following is done:

Let $v$ be a vector, and $E \subseteq I$ an arbitrary subset of the (possible uncountable) index set $I$ and consider
$$
 v_E = \sum_{i \in E} c_i(v) e_i
$$
with $c_i(v) = \langle v, e_i \rangle$.

Then in the proof it is concluded that $\sum_{i \in E} |c_i(v)|^2 \le ||v||^2$, and so
$$
  \sum_{i \in I} |c_i(v)|^2 \le ||v||^2. (*)
$$
And then it is said because of that just countable many $c_i(v)$ could be unequal to $0$ and that the series of the $|c_i(v)|^2$ converges.

I don't see why because of (*) the set $\{ c_i(v) | c_i(v) \ne 0 \}$ is countable?

Comment: A remark: the orthogonal basis is not dense itself, it is its linear span that is dense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I_n$ be the set of all $i$ for which $|c_i(v)| > 1/n$. We have:

$$
\sum_{i \in I_n} |n c_i(v)|^2 \le n^2 \sum_{i \in I} |c_i(v)|^2 < \infty
$$

Notice that each term in the LHS sum is larger than $1$. Thus, the number of elements in each $I_n$ must be finite. We conclude that $\bigcup_n I_n = \{i \mid c_i(v) \ne 0\}$ is at most countable.

Answer (score 3):

First, given an uncountable index set $I$ and nonnegative numbers $d_i$ for $i\in I$, what do we even mean by the expression $\sum_{i\in I} d_i$? Well, we mean the following,

$$ \sum_{i\in I} d_i = \sup_{F\subset I} \sum_{i\in F} d_i, $$
where $F$ is finite (You can give a definition when the $d_i$ are no longer nonnegative, but then the sum isn't necessarily defined, i.e., doesn't converge to anything).

Now that we have this definition, we claim the following proposition.

**Proposition.** Given any uncountable collection $d_i>0$ of *positive* numbers indexed by $I$, the sum $\sum_{i\in I} d_i$ is infinite.

*Proof.* Let $E_0=\{i\in I\mid d_i>1\}$ and $E_n=\{i\in I\mid \frac{1}{n+1}<d_i\le\frac{1}{n}$. Then the $E_n$ are disjoint and their union is $I$. As a result, there is some $k$ for which $E_k$ is infinite (otherwise $I$ would be a countable union of finite sets and therefore countable). Then we can choose arbitrarily large finite subsets $F\subset E_k\subset I$ and for these we have

$$ \sum_{i\in F} d_i \ge \sum_{i\in F} \frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{\vert F\vert}{k+1} $$
Since $k$ is fixed, the right-hand side can become arbitrarily large, and hence the supremum over all finite subsets of $I$ is infinite. #

Now, an application of this proposition is that if the sum over every finite subset of $I$ is uniformly bounded (say by $\Vert v\Vert^2$), then the sum over $I$ is finite and less than or equal to this uniform bound. Hence, the set $\{i\in I\mid d_i>0\}$ is at most countable.