# Hilbert space with uncountable basis

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$, where $I$ is an uncountable index set. How to prove that for any $x\in H$, there exists countable $(e_i)_{i\geq 1}$ such that
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i.$$

**Idea**: Since $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis, then $\mathrm{span}((e_i)_{i\in I})$ is dense in $H$, so there exists a sequence $(x^{(n)})_{n\geq 1}$ which converges to $x$, and for each $x^{(n)}$, it can be represented as a finite linear combination:
$$x^{(n)}=\sum_{i\in J_n}x^{(n)}_i e_i,$$
where $J_n\subset I$ is finite index set.

**Another question**: We know that if Hilbert space $H$ has a countable orthonormal basis $(e_i)_{i\geq 1}$, then $\forall x\in H$, we have the Parseval identity $x=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i$. But in this case where the orthonormal basis is uncountable, does the Parseval identity $x=\sum_{i\in I}\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i$ hold?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conclusion in the proof that every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis regarding countable index set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258300/conclusion-in-the-proof-that-every-hilbert-space-has-an-orthonormal-basis-regard)

Answer (score 1):

For each positive integer $n>0$, you can show: the set $Z_n=\{i\in I:|\langle x,e_i \rangle |>\frac{1}{n}\}$ is a finite set. Then $\bigcup_{n}Z_n$ is countable. So only countable $i\in I$ will make $\langle x,e_i \rangle $ to be nonzero.